# Javascript: How to use a unique URL taken from different directories

Tags: javascript, url

Sorry if the title is not clear I clarify what I want to do.

I have a main.js which is used by all my pages.
In this main.js I have some URLs: let's say

```
var myImgUrl = "/img/thisPicture.png";
```

The problem is that main.js is used by different pages which are in different directories respect to main.js. This means that the path should be different.

For example, let's say my directories's like this

- js > main.js
- img > thisPicture.png
- index.html
- bio > mybio.html
- activities > myActivity.html

now, of course from pages `"myActivity.html"`, `"mybio.html"` and `index.html` there will be three different paths to get to thisPicture.png but they all three use main.js as script file.

Question: is it possible to write a for `myImgUrl` which will be unique for all files? And, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full path to the file you are wanting to reference instead of a relative path.

```
var myImgUrl = "https://www.example.com/img/thisPicture.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example image path is an absolute path, so that should work fine for any html file. The reason that it is an absolute path, is that it starts with a slash, meaning the root of the current basedir (usually your domain root).

CSS files use the css file to resolve relative paths, but Javascript uses the document. So the statements below should be true for Javascript and HTML paths.

So, for `/img/thisPicture.png`

- index.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`
- bio/mybio.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`
- activities/myActivity.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`

If we skip the initial / and thereby make it a relative path, we get a different result.
For `img/thisPicture.png`

- index.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`
- bio/mybio.html will load: `/bio/img/thisPicture.png`
- activities/myActivity.html will load: `/activities/img/thisPicture.png`

HTML allows you to change your base dir using the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. This will set a new base directory for all relative paths. So the second example, combined with a base tag to '/' would give us:

For `img/thisPicture.png` and every html page containing a `<base href="/">` in the `<head>`

- index.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`
- bio/mybio.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`
- activities/myActivity.html will load: `/img/thisPicture.png`